# My Django app doesnt Run again on my local computer Since i changed to Heroku postgrel database

Tags: python, django, heroku

my database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        #'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'DatabaseName',
    }
}
DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=True)
```

When ever I try run the server on my computer it shows the error .It happened when i tried changing my database fromsqlite to postgre.

the error

```
 File "C:\Users\stephen\favprojects\favprojects\settings.py", line 94, in <module>
    DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
  File "C:\Users\stephen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DATABASE_URL'
```

Comment: Either set the environmental variable `DATABASE_URL` or create an seperate config file for your local instance.

Comment: Please explain further